# MongoDB query to get last record of each id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to get last record of each **sender.id** based on **createdAt** using mongodb query.

Sample json:

```
{
    "code" : "34242342",
    "name" : "name1",
    "amount" : 200,
    "sender" : {
        "id" : "fsrfsr3242",
        "name" : "name2",
        "phone" : "12345678",
        "category": "cat1"
    },
    "receiver" : {
        "id" : "42342rewr",
        "name" : "naem3",
        "phone" : "5653679755"
    },
    "message" : "",
    "status" : "done",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-09-27T09:17:32.597Z")
}
```

Query i tried:

```
[{
    $match: {
        'sender.category': "cat1"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$sender.id",
        lastrecord: {
            $last: "$createdAt"
        }
    }
}]
```

I want to return **entire json** as above with only last record of each sender.id. Above query is only giving me only last date , How do i return entire json using aggregation pipeline?

I am using **groupby** because each sender.id can have multiple records of which i only want to retrieve the last one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`$$ROOT`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) variable to get the whole last document

```
[
  { "$match": { "sender.category": "cat1" }},
  { "$sort": { "$createdAt": 1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$sender.id",
    "lastrecord": {
      "$last": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }}
]
```

Comment: I was using last to get the latest document based on createdAt field. I have a minor confusion regarding, it will return the last document or the latest document? @Ashh

Comment: `{ "$sort": { "$createdAt": 1 }}` this will `$sort` your documents and then will give you the last document.

Comment: For many records this query can be extremely slow. Simply doing a for...each sender.id loop of a simple ```find``` query can give much much faster results in my experience. For exapmle: loop through ```.find({ "sender.id": "id_123}).sort({ "createdAt": -1 }).limit(1)```